# Unable to get array in controller from ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Not getting array of data from ajax to controller.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Home/List",
      traditional: true,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: {
        "Query": JSON.stringify(Query) //change this
        success: function() {}
      });,
```

And array of Query :

> ```
>   0: {label: "abc:", value: "123", type: "Select"} 1: {label: "xyz",
>   value: "Hum", type: "text"}
> ```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think something along this may work for you.

```
 function sendarray() {
        var arr = [];
        var json = {
            "label": 'abc',
            "value": 1234,
            "Name": 'Name'
        };
        arr.push(json);
        json = {
            "label": 'abc2',
            "value": 1234,
            "Name": 'Name2'
        };
        arr.push(json);    
        var myarray = JSON.stringify(arr);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller/GetArray',
            type: 'POST',            
            data: { array: myarray },
            success: function (data) {
                    //Do something
            },
            error: function () {
                //Do something
            }
        });
    }
```

then in the controller

```
public JsonResult GetArray(string array)
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(array);
            return Json("");
        }
```

This will send an string with all the data in the array to the controller, then you turn string with json format into an object list

Comment: How to get this array in controller ?

Comment: The controller would receive a json string, that string you would then deserialize or instead of a  json.stringify you send the object you wan to receive.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var  query=[{label: "abc:", value: "123", type: "Select"},{label: "abc:", value: "1232", type: "Select"} ];
  $.ajax({ type: "POST",
   url: "/Home/List", 
   traditional: true, 
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(query),
   success: function (){

   } });

</script>
```

Comment: But how to  get this data in controller plz help me